# Material-UI: Module parse failed: Unterminated string constant (18:5)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have updated the latest material-ui version (@material-ui/core : 3.0.3, @material-ui/icons: 3.01). When I run npm start. The terminal showed the error below:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder.js
Module parse failed: Unterminated string constant (18:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   d: "M0 0h24v24H0z"
| }), _react.default.createElement("path", {
|   d: "M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28
22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5
```

My environment: @material-ui/core: v3.0.3, @material-ui/icon: v3.0.1, React: 16.4.2

Comment: show your webpack config

Answer (score 0):

You need to install those packages, I think they might not be in your `node_modules` Do the following

```
$ npm install
$ npm run start
```